# echo HTML tag into php input value

Tags: php, html

I have problem , I want to echo the string which is html tag, so I don't know how to say that but this is my code

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value='.($row['id']).'>';
```

where the value of $row['id'] is `'<b>test</b>'`, the problem is on the output of the echo, the closing tag of `<b>` will close the input tag, so the value of input just `'<b'` 
thanks.

Comment: run it through htmlentities function.

Comment: Your just missing a set of double quotes around the value..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`htmlentities($row['id'],ENT_QUOTES)` this will encode `<` `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";


echo htmlentities($str);
// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;

echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
```

Both above are correct, second one safer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Pass data through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to make it safe for inserting into HTML attributes (by converting characters with special meaning to entities).
2. Quote attribute values (your code doesn't have `"` around the outputted row id) so that spaces, `=` and so on will be treated as part of the value

Such:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'. htmlspecialchars($row['id']) . '">';
```

Or, better yet, don't output chunks of markup in PHP mode, switch to straight output mode until you need a variable / function call:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']); ?>">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `htmlspecialchars` within your echo statement, like so:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['id']) . '">';
```

Also added quote marks for the value of `value`.

Comment: Use what? This is a game of spot-the-difference. Answers should explain what they are doing.

Comment: It's pretty obvious what had changed. Regardless, I've edited it to make it crystal clear.

Comment: You have also added quote marks around the value attribute's value. Those aren't obvious. Quote marks are easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to properly escape:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.($row['id']).'">';
```

Comment: I'd use `"` instead of `\'` since other attributes are in double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You will get what you want :-

htmlentities($this->input->post('txtEditor'));